# how create custom scrollbar in a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I make my own scrollbar in a div content with jquery.
I just make a div for content & append a div in that div at right side.

My current code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ln7wfoz7/

```js
var scrollheight = $("#demo").prop("srollHeight");
var scrollblock = '<div class="custom">'+'</div>';

$("#demo").append(scrollblock);

var scrollbar = '<div class="scrollbar">'+'</div>';

$(".custom").append(scrollbar);
```

```css
#demo{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    position: relative;
}

p{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.custom{
    height: 100%;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #abaaa7;   
}

.scrollbar{
    height: 20px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: darkorange;
    border-radius: 30%;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
           <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu augue id elit dignissim pretium. Nulla ut metus diam. Vivamus mattis sodales massa eu viverra. Fusce elementum dui lacus, nec porttitor velit. Donec vehicula mollis tincidunt. Proin tellus tortor, egestas vel ultrices ullamcorper, accumsan sit amet ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id purus non justo porttitor pretium. Cras in ipsum dui, ut rutrum nibh. Donec gravida pellentesque fermentum. Nunc tincidunt gravida ligula at dictum. Integer eu orci nec arcu rhoncus facilisis aliquet id metus.

            Aliquam id tempus risus. Donec id odio id dui rutrum dictum. Donec mollis lacus a metus congue porta. Morbi tincidunt elit vel augue venenatis vestibulum. Quisque auctor orci at elit aliquet ullamcorper volutpat nunc feugiat. Phasellus commodo tristique quam, ac mattis odio scelerisque nec. Phasellus nec lobortis odio. Nunc risus mauris, sollicitudin bibendum porta ultricies, vehicula eu odio. Praesent non lorem diam. Nunc sit amet arcu justo, et venenatis magna. Etiam elementum ipsum eu dui interdum aliquet. Duis scelerisque congue venenatis. Quisque fringilla dui sed felis elementum placerat. Donec ultrices sodales eros viverra vulputate.

            Donec eu quam nunc, in pharetra libero. Etiam egestas, libero a molestie dapibus, elit neque lobortis nisl, interdum dictum mauris mauris quis enim. Proin porta, nulla et condimentum lobortis, risus lorem ultrices tortor, id cursus nulla libero et lacus. Pellentesque dapibus, erat non vehicula congue, neque est mollis risus, id ornare turpis leo eu eros. Suspendisse commodo elementum odio, in semper est malesuada nec. Praesent et tincidunt mi. Phasellus sodales felis nisl. Pellentesque sit amet arcu justo, auctor adipiscing mauris. Aenean aliquam consequat massa, vitae molestie neque gravida et. Phasellus vehicula euismod porta. Donec eget est enim. Cras mattis commodo sagittis. Vivamus at mauris eu tellus pulvinar pretium a sit amet diam. Pellentesque quis tortor libero. Phasellus eleifend, risus sit amet blandit ultrices, tellus ligula consequat libero, sit amet gravida nunc odio vel turpis. Vestibulum accumsan orci in velit ornare sed venenatis quam consequat.

            Vestibulum justo massa, varius vitae pellentesque in, mollis quis ipsum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed vulputate erat nec purus lacinia at ultrices diam semper. Vivamus eget fermentum purus. Nam sit amet libero justo, congue accumsan dolor. Pellentesque imperdiet lobortis urna sed sollicitudin. Curabitur ac magna quis lacus commodo varius eu ac dui. Aliquam vel mauris tellus. Donec facilisis sem tempor turpis faucibus auctor. Proin tincidunt adipiscing nunc, et pellentesque metus iaculis eu.

            In convallis rutrum pretium. Praesent lobortis felis sed elit placerat sit amet suscipit enim rhoncus. Sed imperdiet pretium ullamcorper. Duis nec varius lacus. Nulla rutrum molestie tortor, a ornare sem tristique ac. Quisque rhoncus felis id augue viverra consectetur. Cras condimentum dapibus risus, eget condimentum mauris ultrices ac. Cras vel augue eros, vitae volutpat felis. Sed feugiat vulputate diam, vitae accumsan augue rhoncus non. Nullam non dolor diam.
           </p>
</div>
```

**Note**

I do not want to use the default scrollbar, nor do I wish to use a plugin

Comment: Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln7wfoz7/

Comment: show me the html code you use

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln7wfoz7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln7wfoz7/1/

Comment: @Sagar - You've put overflow to hidden which will hide the scrollbar! Make this auto and it will be ok.

Comment: I want to make my own scrollbar. So I hide overflow for appending a div for scrollbar here.

Comment: you can use this http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: auto;` instead of `overflow: hidden;` in class/(id) `demo`

Comment: I want to make my own scrollbar. So I hide overflow for appending a div for scrollbar here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:auto` instead of `overflow:hidden`. Because hidden doesn't makes scroll they just do hide the content and you want scroll use overflow : auto or scroll in css

```
#demo{
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    position: relative;
     overflow:auto;

}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln7wfoz7/2/)

Comment: I want to make my own scrollbar. So I hide overflow for appending a div for scrollbar here.

Comment: I want to make my own scrollbar. So I hide overflow for appending a div for scrollbar here.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#demo{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    position: relative;

}
```

That will create a vertical scroll bar to your `#demo` div.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln7wfoz7/4/)

Comment: I want to make my own scrollbar. So I hide overflow for appending a div for scrollbar here.